# Conceptually, why is the entropy of black hole related to Planck length?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, entropy, quantum-gravity, holographic-principle

I was watching a lecture on the holographic principle, and it presented the equation for the entropy of a black hole as $$S_{BH} = \frac{A}{4l_p^2}$$ My question is why, conceptually, the entropy of a black hole should be related to Planck length?

Comment: What does $A$ stand for?

Comment: Well, if we defined the Planck length & Boltzmann constant differently, the equation would have the same form, but there'd be another constant instead of 1/4.

Comment: @hft A is the area of the event horizon, in Schwarzschild coordinates, i.e $4\pi r_s^2$. Bear in mind that the Schwarzschild radius $r_s$ isn't *really* the radius of the BH. It's defined in terms of the circumference or area of the event horizon.

Comment: If I had to guess, it seems like there might be some counting argument where the number of states (or its log) is related to how many different way you can divide up $A$ into squares of size $2\ell_p$, or something like that. But I don't really know.

Comment: See the PBS Space Time video [The Black Hole Entropy Enigma](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ab8JIzckx_M&list=PLsPUh22kYmNBl4h0i4mI5zDflExXJMo_x&index=14)

Comment: The nondimensionalized entropy can only be equated to a nondimensionalized multiple of $A$. Dimensional analysis forces $G\hbar/c^3$ into the RHS's denominator. It also makes $\sqrt{G\hbar/c^3}$ the only length we can make out of $c,\,G,\,\hbar$.

Answer (score 2):

In classical general relativity there is no deep explanation, since we don't consider quantum mechanics. The appearance of the Planck length is due to the [Geometrized unit system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrized_unit_system) commonly used in general relativity. Since the area has the dimensionality of a squared length we need a factor in the denominator with squared length dimensions, so that the entropy is dimensionless. The Planck length is usually chosen as a unit of reference, since it is naturally obtained without any multiplicative factor from the combination of common constants such as $c$, $G$ and $\hbar$. Indeed the Planck length is central to other systems of units, such as the [Planck units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units).

The real question is why does the Planck length arise with a $O(1)$ factor in the formula?

One can make many arguments such as that the Planck length arises due to:

- The quantum nature of the underlying statistical microstates. Original Bekenstein quote:

> The appearance of $\hbar$ is “... a reflection of the fact that the entropy
> is ... a count of states of the system, and the underlying states are
> quantum in nature ... . It would be somewhat pretentious to calculate
> the precise value of η without a full understanding of the quantum
> reality which underlies a ‘classical’ black hole”

- Black holes evaporation and thermodynamic nature, similarly to a regular black body radiation.
- Quantum gravity holographic nature of the black hole, as suggested by the presence of the area.
- The relation to the entanglement entropy of quantum fields and quantum extremal surfaces (see [Ryu–Takayanagi conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryu%E2%80%93Takayanagi_conjecture))

But to my knowledge we still lack a convincing and deep argument about the (1) factor. We need a better understanding of the quantum theory of which gravity is a coarse grained picture.